# Java Wrapper: что ждет от моего класса JVM?

Tags: java, jsp, jvm, streamwrapper

Здравствуйте.

Пытаюсь в windows запустить main.jar как службу.
Для этих целей решил воспользоваться функционалом java wrapper community edition 3.5.29
При старте службы возникает ошибка wrapper при том, что необходимый jar стартует нормально.

```
STATUS | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:53:21 | --> Wrapper Started as Service
STATUS | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:53:21 | Java Service Wrapper Community Edition 32-bit 3.5.29
STATUS | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:53:21 |   Copyright (C) 1999-2016 Tanuki Software, Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:53:21 |     http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com
STATUS | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:53:21 |
STATUS | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:53:22 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/07/19 11:53:22 | [11:53:22 19.07.2016]: Запуск главного процесса. Работаем с БД Oracle.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/07/19 11:53:22 | [11:53:22 19.07.2016]: Попытка первого Update.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/07/19 11:53:22 | [11:53:22 19.07.2016]: Update выполнен.
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 | Startup failed: Timed out waiting for a signal from the JVM.
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 |
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 | ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 | Advice:
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 | The Wrapper consists of a native component as well as a set of classes
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 | which run within the JVM that it launches.  The Java component of the
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 | Wrapper must be initialized promptly after the JVM is launched or the
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 | Wrapper will timeout, as just happened.  Most likely the main class
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 | specified in the Wrapper configuration file is not correctly initializing
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 | the Wrapper classes:
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 |     COM.MainRunner
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 | While it is possible to do so manually, the Wrapper ships with helper
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 | classes to make this initialization processes automatic.
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 | Please review the integration section of the Wrapper's documentation
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 | for the various methods which can be employed to launch an application
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 | within the Wrapper:
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 |     http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/integrate.html
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 | ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 |
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 | JVM did not exit on request, termination requested.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 | JVM exited after being requested to terminate.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:26 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2016/07/19 11:54:26 | [11:54:26 19.07.2016]: Запуск главного процесса. Работаем с БД Oracle.
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2016/07/19 11:54:26 | [11:54:26 19.07.2016]: Попытка первого Update.
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2016/07/19 11:54:27 | [11:54:26 19.07.2016]: Update выполнен.
```

настройки conf

```
    #********************************************************************
# Wrapper Java Properties
#********************************************************************
# Java Application
#  Locate the java binary on the system PATH:
wrapper.java.command=java
#  Specify a specific java binary:
#set.JAVA_HOME=/java/path
#wrapper.java.command=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java

# Tell the Wrapper to log the full generated Java command line.
#wrapper.java.command.loglevel=INFO

# Java Main class.  This class must implement the WrapperListener interface
#  or guarantee that the WrapperManager class is initialized.  Helper
#  classes are provided to do this for you.  See the Integration section
#  of the documentation for details.
#wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.demo.DemoApp
wrapper.java.mainclass=COM.MainRunner

# Java Classpath (include wrapper.jar)  Add class path elements as
#  needed starting from 1
wrapper.java.classpath.1=main.jar
#wrapper.java.classpath.2=wrapper.jar

# Java Library Path (location of Wrapper.DLL or libwrapper.so)
wrapper.java.library.path.1=lib

# Java Bits.  On applicable platforms, tells the JVM to run in 32 or 64-bit mode.
wrapper.java.additional.auto_bits=TRUE

# Java Additional Parameters
wrapper.java.additional.1=

# Initial Java Heap Size (in MB)
#wrapper.java.initmemory=3

# Maximum Java Heap Size (in MB)
#wrapper.java.maxmemory=64

# Application parameters.  Add parameters as needed starting from 1
wrapper.app.parameter.1="Oracle"

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Logging Properties
#********************************************************************
# Enables Debug output from the Wrapper.
# wrapper.debug=TRUE

# Format of output for the console.  (See docs for formats)
wrapper.console.format=PM

# Log Level for console output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.console.loglevel=INFO

# Log file to use for wrapper output logging.
wrapper.logfile=logs/wrapper.log

# Format of output for the log file.  (See docs for formats)
wrapper.logfile.format=LPTM

# Log Level for log file output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.logfile.loglevel=INFO

# Maximum size that the log file will be allowed to grow to before
#  the log is rolled. Size is specified in bytes.  The default value
#  of 0, disables log rolling.  May abbreviate with the 'k' (kb) or
#  'm' (mb) suffix.  For example: 10m = 10 megabytes.
wrapper.logfile.maxsize=0

# Maximum number of rolled log files which will be allowed before old
#  files are deleted.  The default value of 0 implies no limit.
wrapper.logfile.maxfiles=0

# Log Level for sys/event log output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.syslog.loglevel=NONE

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper General Properties
#********************************************************************
# Allow for the use of non-contiguous numbered properties
wrapper.ignore_sequence_gaps=TRUE

# Do not start if the pid file already exists.
wrapper.pidfile.strict=TRUE

# Title to use when running as a console
wrapper.console.title=UM_Scheduler

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper JVM Checks
#********************************************************************
# Detect DeadLocked Threads in the JVM. (Requires Standard Edition)
wrapper.check.deadlock=TRUE
wrapper.check.deadlock.interval=10
wrapper.max_failed_invocations=99
wrapper.console.fatal_to_stderr=FALSE
wrapper.console.error_to_stderr=FALSE
wrapper.check.deadlock.action=RESTART
wrapper.check.deadlock.output=FULL

# Out Of Memory detection.
#  Ignore -verbose:class output to avoid false positives.
wrapper.filter.trigger.1000=[Loaded java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
wrapper.filter.action.1000=NONE
# (Simple match)
wrapper.filter.trigger.1001=java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
# (Only match text in stack traces if -XX:+PrintClassHistogram is being used.)
#wrapper.filter.trigger.1001=Exception in thread "*" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
#wrapper.filter.allow_wildcards.1001=TRUE
wrapper.filter.action.1001=RESTART
wrapper.filter.message.1001=The JVM has run out of memory.
```

Прошу помочь разобраться в проблеме. 
Чего ждет от моего класса JVM?

Comment: необходим простейший работающий пример класса с implements WrapperListener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

удалось решить вопрос через правку conf

```
решение через изменение настроек conf #wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.demo.DemoApp
#wrapper.java.mainclass=COM.MainTaskRunner
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
# Java Classpath (include wrapper.jar)  Add class path elements as
#  needed starting from 1
#wrapper.java.classpath.1=../lib/wrapperdemo.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.1=C:/New/MainRunner.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=../lib/wrapper.jar
# Java Library Path (location of Wrapper.DLL or libwrapper.so)
wrapper.java.library.path.1=../lib
wrapper.java.library.path.2=C:/New/MainRunner/lib

# Java Bits.  On applicable platforms, tells the JVM to run in 32 or 64-bit mode.
wrapper.java.additional.auto_bits=TRUE

# Java Additional Parameters
wrapper.java.additional.1=

# Initial Java Heap Size (in MB)
#wrapper.java.initmemory=3

# Maximum Java Heap Size (in MB)
#wrapper.java.maxmemory=64

# Application parameters.  Add parameters as needed starting from 1
#wrapper.app.parameter.1="Oracle"


# The first application parameter is the name of the class whose main
# method is to be called when the application is launched.  The class
# name is followed by the number of parameters to be passed to its main
# method.  Then comes the actual parameters.
wrapper.app.parameter.1=COM.MainRunner
wrapper.app.parameter.2="Oracle"
```